# Restrict user access to server files

Tags: windows, security, windows-server-2012-r2, filesystems

I have 2 Windows Server 2012 R2 virtual machines that has about 250 logons.

The ***Files Server*** has all the users files on `D:\userdocs\(username)`.

The ***Desktop Server*** has all the software and programs and is where the users logon to and using folder redirection they have their files from the *Files Server*.

The only issue is that currently, any user can browse almost all `C:\` drive files and in certain places can create his own folders and files hidden deep in the files of the *Desktop Server*.
Each user can also edit the permissions of folders on his desktop and by doing that create shares to other users.
We need to keep a high security level in our servers and the above does cause some issues for us.

What I want to find out if there is a way that a **user's applications can have access to certain folders on the `C:\` drive** of the *Desktop Server* although at the same time **restrict the users access to those folders so he cannot browse them or add and remove files.**

I also want to see if I can **restrict a user from changing his desktop file permissions** so that he cannot change the security settings on it and I am the only one that can. I know I can take ownership of his desktop and change the security settings although I do not feel like this is the correct way to handle this.

Comment: Is the desktop server running TS and you're having 250 users log into it for workspaces?  Are all of the users set up as administrators, that they're changing stuff on C: of this VM?

Comment: @RobPearson It is running Terminal Services, it does have 250 users using it for workspaces. There are only 3 administrator accounts (default and 2 IT admins). They are able to change certain files on C and deep in the C drive they can change files. They can also create shared folders right from their desktop.